# Why was Mickey framed?

Tags: plot-explanation, payback-2021

According to [this review](https://otakukart.com/payback-review/), in *Payback (2021)*, the whole mob gang designed a shoot-out and framed Mickey for manslaughter.

Why was Mickey framed? What was the gang's objective?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mickey was framed because he found out that Ricky/Pushka were stealing from their clients.

As he says:

> Frank Watkins calls me, asks me for his money back.
>
> I tell Ricky. He sends me to LA to work with Slava. And I get sent on
> some bullshit pickup that gets Boone killed and lands me in jail.
>
> The next week, the same amount that Frank invested is transferred into
> someone else's account.
>
> Ricky was stealing from Frank, not just convincing him to buy shady stock.
> He was putting your whole operation at risk and I found out about it.